# How to remove landmarks while using MapKit API (iOS)?

Tags: ios, api, maps, mapkit

What function would be able to hide local landmarks when browsing a confined region via Apple Maps API ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called `showsPointsOfInterest` for `MKMapView`, you can set it to `NO` to hide icons and labels for restaurants, schools, and other relevant points of interest.

Answer (score 0):

showsPointsOfInterest is deprecated.

With IOS 13 you have the option to filter: here a example to show no items on the map

```
mapView.pointOfInterestFilter = .some(MKPointOfInterestFilter(including: []))
```